CPQ Custom Script Running User Id
I am working  in new functionalities  to enforce the   isFieldEditableForObject /  isFieldVisibleForObject .
Is there a way on the JS  CPQ custom script code to get the current running user id?
I would like to avoid creating new formula fields to capture the $User.CustomField.. or $User.Id
Thanks in advance
